# Python create new file every day to write on

Tags: python

I have program in python, which reads the data from the api and writes it to the file eth.txt.
I would like to program create a new file with a date name every day, like eth_9.11.2018.txt, eth_10.11.2018.txt, ....  and then write on it.
Can you help me ?

```
import time
import threading
import urllib
import datetime


while True:
    ts = time.time()
    h = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S') 
    d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
    # read from API
    ethash = urlopen('https://www.coincalculators.io/api/allcoins.aspx?hashrate=420000000&power=2000&powercost=0.15&difficultytime=0&algorithm=Ethash').read()
    dataethash= json.loads(ethash)
    global coinethash,algoethash,dayUSDethash,dayEUethash
    coinethash = dataethash[0]["name"] 
    algoethash = dataethash[0]["algorithm"] 
    dayUSDethash = dataethash[0]["profitInDayUSD"]
    diffethash = dataethash[0]["currentDifficulty"]
    print ("Difficulty:"),diffethash
    print ("Algoritm:"),algoethash
    print ("Coin:"),coinethash
    dayUSDethash = float(dayUSDethash)
    dayEUethash = dayUSDethash*0.88
    # Write ti file
    profit = open("/home/pi/Skripte/eth.txt", "a")    
    profit.write(str(h))
    profit.write('*')
    profit.write(str(d))
    profit.write('*')
    profit.write(str(algoethash))
    profit.write('*')
    profit.write(str(diffethash))
    profit.write('*')
    profit.write(str(coinethash))
    profit.write('*')
    profit.write(str("%.2f" % dayEUethash))
    profit.write('*')
    profit.write("\n") #new line
    print("OK")
    time.sleep(500)
```

..and by the way... 
Is it possible block "#write to file" write in a more friendly and short way? 
It must contain a character * between words, and must write in a new line...
Thankyou for help!

Comment: for the *#write to file* block, try [`'*'.join([str(h), str(d), str(...), ...])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: Can you clarify? What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler)

Comment: Using yyyy-mm-dd rather than dd.mm.yyyy is almost certainly going to be a good idea.

Comment: please explore the link in @MikeScotty comment; as well as review the examples in the [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define dynamically the name of the file you want to write.
In this case, `eth_{}.txt'.format(d)` will append the current day to it.

To write in the file more elegantly, you can join the list your strings with '*' in one line.

```
with open('eth_{}.txt'.format(d), 'a') as profit:
    profit.write('*'.join([str(x) for x in [h, d, algoethash, diffethash, coinethash, "%.2f" % dayEUethash, '\n']]))
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Using `'a'` for a file which doesn't yet exist is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Reupiey , first "eth_{}.txt'.format(d)" work fine, thankyou, but second to write more elegantly not work - i thing is a problem with bracket.. i try this,`with open('eth_{}.txt'.format(d), 'a') as profit:` and
        `profit.write('*').join([str(x) for x in [h, d, algoethash, diffethash, coinethash, "%.2f" % dayEUethash, '\n']])` but have error  'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'join' '

Comment: @McDam Yes, sorry, I forgot a bracket ! The new error you have is because it tries to apply 'join' to the result of profit.write('\*') which is None, try this instead : `profit.write('*'.join([str(x) for x in [h, d, algoethash, diffethash, coinethash, "%.2f" % dayEUethash, '\n']]))`

Comment: @Reupiey KING!!!  Work perfect, thankyou..... ( I thought I was try all bracketing combinations, but obviously not, hahahaaaa )